# How do I send an API Request in batches of 1000 items in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a list of IDs coming from a Database. Now I want to send out an API request that includes the list of IDs in the request. I can only send 1000 IDs in one API request.

Currently, I'm building an Array for the API Request based on the DB ID'S with a for Each loop. This loops through the retuned list of a lookup.

Now my problem is that I need to handle the case when the DB returns more than 1000 items. How can I batch the request by chunks of 1000 items.

[image: My current setup]

1. Check Values: Gets the ID from the DB
2. For each, loops through the results and builds the array for the JSON.
3. The If conditions checks, if there are any values returned, if yes it sends the request to the API. Otherwise no request is send.

Answer (score 1):

For your pipeline to work when the look up returns either less than or equal to 1000 records or for more than thousand rows, you can use the following approach.

- First use `lookup` to get the all the id records. Then instead of using `if condition`, **use a set variable and make use of both success flow and failure flow** as an if condition instead, to check if the returned records are more than 1000 or not.
- I used a string variable, used `if` function to check whether the count of records are less than or equal to 1000 or not. If yes, then I use that count (converted to string) if the condition is false, directly assign any integer value (so that the activity fails throwing an error where we can use the failure flow to implement batch logic for records greater than 1000)

```
@if(less(activity('Lookup1').output.count,1001),string(activity('Lookup1').output.count),0)
```

[image]

- If condition is true and records are less than thousand, directly pass the lookup array to an execute pipeline activity. This `execute pipeline` activity must contain your `send request` activities.

[image]

- If there are more than 1000 records, we need to take batches of 1000 until all the records are read. Using the failure flow of our `fake_if` variable, take a new variable left (indicating number of records left to send request.)

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.count)
```

[image]

- I took another variable to count the number of records processed as `done`.

```
@string(0)
```

[image]

- Now use `until` activity to process until the `left` value is less than `0`.

```
@less(int(variables('left')),0)
```

[image]

- Now, use the same `execute pipeline` activity and pass the following array process.

```
@if(greater(int(variables('left')),999),take(skip(activity('Lookup1').output.value,int(variables('done'))),1000),take(skip(activity('Lookup1').output.value,int(variables('done'))),int(variables('left'))))
```

[image]

- Now we have to update the values of `left` and `done` where we increment the value of `done` and decrement the value of `left`.
- Since we can't self-reference a variable, we have to take a temporary reference variable and then update it.
- To update the value of  `done`, I have taken as `change_done` variable with following value.

```
@string(add(int(variables('done')),pipeline().parameters.thousand))
```

[image]

- Assign the above `change_done` value to `done` variable.

[image]

- Follow similarly for `left` as well. The following is an entire debug output when there are 2500 records.

[image]

**NOTE:** Since you are getting the data from database, you can query to get records in batches using sort and Row number and implementing the same logic as above (in case there are more than 5000 records).